# HTTP/1.1 Post to D-Link Camera

Tags: http, post, http-status-code-404

I am trying to use an HTTP POST command directly to a D-Link DCS-932L camera (I have one camera on F/W 1.12 and another on 1.14, if that helps). I keep getting the 404 File Not Found error.

Running Fiddler, I've turned on motion in the browser and seen the following request:

```
POST /setSystemMotion HTTP/1.1
```

Syntax is

```
ReplySuccessPage=motion.htm&ReplyErrorPage=motion.htm&MotionDetectionEnable=1&MotionDetectionScheduleDay=0&MotionDetectionScheduleMode=0&MotionDetectionSensitivity=45&ConfigSystemMotion=Save
```

If I try to turn on motion using an HTTP POST command via the Chrome Extension Postman using the exact same request and syntax I get

```
<html><body><h2>Error: File Not Found</h2>
<p>getfile: Cannot open URL(/etc_ro/web/setform/setSystemMotion,No such file or directory)</p></body></html>
```

It seems that the camera's server has decided to route my ./setSystemMotion to this ./etc_ro/web/setform folder. I'm happy to provide more details, but can anybody shed some light on what might cause that change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue.
resolved with this curl command taken from the below forum

```
curl "http://<IP>/setSystemMotion" -H "Host: <IP>" \
  -H "Referer: http://<IP>/setSystemMotion" -H "Authorization: Basic <AuthCode>" \ 
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" \
  --data "ReplySuccessPage=motion.htm&ReplyErrorPage=motion.htm&MotionDetectionEnable=1&MotionDetectionScheduleDay=127&MotionDetectionScheduleMode=1&MotionDetectionScheduleTimeStart=07"%"3A10"%"3A00&MotionDetectionScheduleTimeStop=18"%"3A50"%"3A00&MotionDetectionSensitivity=70&ConfigSystemMotion=Save"
```

https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1424172/systemes/hardware/achat-conseils/peripheriques/camera-ip-commandes-url-api-dlink-dcs-932l/#post8858654